# Dagger/MissingBinding. Outputter cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: java, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, kapt

I'm learning Dagger2 via their tutorial but am blocked at [part 5](https://dagger.dev/tutorial/05-abstraction-for-output). I've implemented everything in Kotlin (jvm) and the logic/behavior matches the tutorial in working order to this point.

However, I'm unable to create `SystemOutModule` and unsure whether I'm mistaken somewhere with Dagger, or in my translation of their module class.

```
/**
* Tutorial's Java.
*/
@Module
abstract class SystemOutModule {
    @Provides
    static Outputter textOutputter() {
        return System.out::println;
    }
}
```

```
/**
* My Kotlin.
*/
@Module
object SystemOutModule {
    @JvmSuppressWildcards
    @Provides
    fun textOutputter(): (String) -> Unit = { println(it) }
}
```

The build fails with this error:

```
~~ ./gradlew clean build


> Task :app:kaptKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/eric/IdeaProjects/atm/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/main/com/es0329/atm/CommandRouterFactory.java:7: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.es0329.atm.Outputter cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface CommandRouterFactory {
                ^
      com.es0329.atm.Outputter is injected at
          com.es0329.atm.HelloWorldCommand(outputter)
      com.es0329.atm.HelloWorldCommand is injected at
          com.es0329.atm.HelloWorldModule.helloWorldCommand(command)
      com.es0329.atm.Command is injected at
          com.es0329.atm.CommandRouter(command)
      com.es0329.atm.CommandRouter is provided at
          com.es0329.atm.CommandRouterFactory.router()

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `HelloWorldCommand` expects an `Outputter`, but you are providing a `(String) -> Unit` instead.  There are a few ways to bridge this gap:

### Option 1: Inject the functional type

Instead of an `Outputter`, your `HelloWorldCommand` can ask for a `(String) -> Unit` directly.

```
class HelloWorldCommand @Inject constructor(private val outputter: (String) -> Unit)
```

This will work, but you might want to provide a different type of `(String) -> Unit` elsewhere in your app.  If you do, you will have to use some sort of `@Qualifier`.

Fortunately, this is the only injected lambda in the entire tutorial as far as I can tell, so it won't be a problem here.

### Option 2: Make `Outputter` a typealias

You can use a typealias to make `Outputter` the same type as `(String) -> Unit`.  This works identically to option 1, but is more expressive.  Unfortunately, it has the same issue if you ever want to have another `(String) -> Unit` in your dependency graph later.

```
typealias Outputter = (String) -> Unit
```

### Option 3: Provide an implementation of the `Outputter` interface

Rather than provide a lambda, you can provide an object implementing `Outputter`.  This is less idiomatic for a simple function, since Kotlin can't assign lambdas directly to SAM interfaces defined in Kotlin.

```
@Provides
fun textOutputter() = object : Outputter {
    override fun output(output: String) = println(output)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nitrodon! I like Option 3 most.